# How to change column order when selecting * in ms access sql?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have the following query

```
SELECT *, 1 AS test FROM tableName
```

It works fine but the *test* column is the first result, I'd like it to be after all the other columns. As far as I can tell this behaviour seems to be exclusive to ms-access, is there a way around it?

Comment: Do not use `*`, write out the column names. That's a general recommendation. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alias could help

```
SELECT a.*
, 1 AS test 
FROM tableName a
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to alias the table, just specify it (`SELECT tablename.*` would be fine as well)